# Change React State with SVG Rect On Click handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

Generally I make sure to include a code example for my problem, however in this case my code is 100% similar to [the following D3 Radio Button example](http://bl.ocks.org/nikhilNathwani/5dca6c63a53934185d05), which I am simply trying to include in a react component of mine.

The relevant code from the example is the on-click handler:

```
.on("click",function(d,i) {
  updateButtonColors(d3.select(this), d3.select(this.parentNode))
  d3.select("#numberToggle").text(i+1)
});
```

however, rather than toggling a number, I am trying to change the state of my react app when this radio button is clicked. For now, let's say I'm simply trying to set the state to be one of 1, 2, or 3, that way *(i + 1)* is the state I'd like to set.

I tried calling setState() directly in the on click handler here, however my state didn't change. Any thoughts on how I can do this? Let me know if more of my code is needed here.

Edit: I've tried adding a snippet of what I have so far, but i'm struggling to get it to work here on stackoverflow.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      chartType: 1
    }
  }
  
  drawChartTypeButton() {
    
    // colors for different button states 
    const defaultColor= "#7777BB"
    const hoverColor= "#0000ff"
    const pressedColor= "#000077"
    const bWidth= 8; //button width
    const bHeight= 5; //button height
    const bSpace= 1; //space between buttons
    const x0 = 5; //x offset
    const y0 = 5; //y offset
    const labels = [1, 2, 3];
    const updateButtonColors = function(button, parent) {
      parent.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("fill",defaultColor)

      button.select("rect")
        .attr("fill",pressedColor)
    }
    
    // groups for each button (which will hold a rect and text)
    const chartTypeButton = d3.select('g.allbuttons')    
    const buttonGroups= chartTypeButton.selectAll("g.button")
      .data(labels)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "button")
      .style("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("click", function(d,i) {
        updateButtonColors(d3.select(this), d3.select(this.parentNode))
        this.setState({chartType: 2})
      })
      .on("mouseover", function() {
        if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
          d3.select(this)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("fill",hoverColor);
        }
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
          d3.select(this)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("fill",defaultColor);
        }
      })
    
    buttonGroups.append("rect")
      .attr("class","buttonRect")
      .attr("width",bWidth)
      .attr("height",bHeight)
      .attr("x", function(d,i) {return x0+(bWidth+bSpace)*i;})
      .attr("y",y0)
      .attr("rx",1) //rx and ry give the buttons rounded corners
      .attr("ry",1)
      .attr("fill",defaultColor)
    
    // adding text to each toggle button group, centered 
    // within the toggle button rect
    buttonGroups.append("text")
      .attr("class","buttonText")
      .attr("font-family", "arial")
      .attr("font-size", "0.1em")
      .attr("x",function(d,i) {
        return x0 + (bWidth+bSpace)*i + bWidth/2;
      })
      .attr("y",y0)
      .attr("text-anchor","middle")
      .attr("dominant-baseline","central")
      .attr("fill","black")
      .text(function(d) {return d;})
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    
    const chart = d3.select('.chart')
      .attr('width', 320)
      .attr('height', 240)
      .attr("viewBox", "0, 0, " + 50 + ", " + 50 + "")
      
    this.drawChartTypeButton();
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div className='container'>
        <svg className='chart'>
          <g className="allbuttons" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
  Damnit Work
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your Radio Buttons code?

Comment: its exactly the same as the blocks link i shared

Comment: Well, can I see where have you tried to use `onClick` handler?

Comment: okay I'll add a snippet of what I've got, one moment

Comment: fixed the snippet so it is at least working with basic functionality

Comment: thanks i edited them a bit more as well to fix the text and also put things in the top left of the svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up the `this` scope inside the click handler, you both use the this for the [d3](/questions/tagged/d3) selector as for the react component.

Normally we could retain the `this` scope using arrow functions, but as you seem to need it for d3 aswell, just create a local variable that saves the current context, so you can reuse it in your click function

```
// create a local reference to "this" in the drawCharTypeButton function
const self = this; 

// use the local reference to update the componenents state
.on("click", function(d,i) {
    updateButtonColors(d3.select(this), d3.select(this.parentNode));
    self.setState({chartType: 2});
})
```

Then your current code would be working (true it only shows the 3 buttons, and selects either of the 3)

Please note that in your sample code, the `chartWidth` and `chartHeight` variable were undefined, so I set them to 320x240 so it matches a bit with the rendering space here on SO

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      chartType: 1
    }
  }
  
  drawChartTypeButton() {
    
    // colors for different button states 
    const defaultColor= "#7777BB"
    const hoverColor= "#0000ff"
    const pressedColor= "#000077"
    const bWidth= 8; //button width
    const bHeight= 6; //button height
    const bSpace= 0.5; //space between buttons
    const x0 = 5; //x offset
    const y0 = 14; //y offset
    const labels = [1, 2, 3];
    const updateButtonColors = function(button, parent) {
      parent.selectAll("rect")
        .attr("fill",defaultColor)

      button.select("rect")
        .attr("fill",pressedColor)
    }
    
    // groups for each button (which will hold a rect and text)
    const self = this;
    const chartTypeButton = d3.select('g.allbuttons')    
    const buttonGroups= chartTypeButton.selectAll("g.button")
      .data(labels)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "button")
      .style("cursor", "pointer")
      .on("click", function(d,i) {
        updateButtonColors(d3.select(this), d3.select(this.parentNode))
        self.setState({chartType: 2})
      })
      .on("mouseover", function() {
        if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
          d3.select(this)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("fill",hoverColor);
        }
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        if (d3.select(this).select("rect").attr("fill") != pressedColor) {
          d3.select(this)
            .select("rect")
            .attr("fill",defaultColor);
        }
      })
    
    buttonGroups.append("rect")
      .attr("class","buttonRect")
      .attr("width",bWidth)
      .attr("height",bHeight)
      .attr("x", function(d,i) {return x0+(bWidth+bSpace)*i;})
      .attr("y",y0)
      .attr("rx",5) //rx and ry give the buttons rounded corners
      .attr("ry",5)
      .attr("fill",defaultColor)
    
    // adding text to each toggle button group, centered 
    // within the toggle button rect
    buttonGroups.append("text")
      .attr("class","buttonText")
      .attr("font-family", "arial")
      .attr("font-size", "0.1em")
      .attr("x",function(d,i) {
        return x0 + (bWidth+bSpace)*i + bWidth/2;
      })
      .attr("y",y0+bHeight/2)
      .attr("text-anchor","middle")
      .attr("dominant-baseline","central")
      .attr("fill","white")
      .text(function(d) {return d;})
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    
    const chart = d3.select('.chart')
      .attr('width', 160)
      .attr('height', 120)
      .attr("viewBox", "0, 0, " + 50 + ", " + 50 + "")
      
    this.drawChartTypeButton();
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div className='container'>
        <svg className='chart'>
          <g className="allbuttons" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'>
  Damnit Work
</div>
```

A nitpick on the combination of [d3](/questions/tagged/d3), [react](/questions/tagged/react), best practice, you should try to do all DOM manipulations inside [react](/questions/tagged/react) instead.

Now for a chart that might not be completely possible, but those 3 buttons can easily be rendered without the need of [d3](/questions/tagged/d3)

I haven't combined these rendering engines yet, so I cannot really say if there are downsides to your current approach

Comment: The buttons are going to toggle between three different charts all drawn out in g3. My actual svg has ~10 <g> tags, not just this one. Depending on the state 1, 2, or 3, certain aspects are or are not drawn onto the graph. Thanks this is great by the way.